# Translation issue with DATATABLE

Tags: datatable

I am trying to include Datatable translation (french language) into the following code.
I want to change few text of the datatable, like **Previous, Next, Show Entries** and the rest

Can someone possibly help me out please?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    var table = $('#prTables').DataTable({

        // 'ajax': '<?=site_url('products/get_products/'.$store->id);?>',
        'ajax' : { url: '<?=site_url('products/get_products/'.$store->id);?>', type: 'POST', "data": function ( d ) {
            d.<?=$this->security->get_csrf_token_name();?> = "<?=$this->security->get_csrf_hash()?>";
        }},
        "buttons": [
        { extend: 'copyHtml5', 'footer': false, exportOptions: { columns: [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 ] } },
        { extend: 'excelHtml5', 'footer': false, exportOptions: { columns: [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 ] } },
        { extend: 'csvHtml5', 'footer': false, exportOptions: { columns: [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 ] } },
        { extend: 'pdfHtml5', orientation: 'landscape', pageSize: 'A4', 'footer': false,
        exportOptions: { columns: [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 ] } },
        { extend: 'colvis', text: 'Columns'},
        ],
        "columns": [
        { "data": "pid", "visible": false },
        { "data": "image", "searchable": false, "orderable": false, "render": image },
        { "data": "code", "visible": false },
        { "data": "pname" },
        { "data": "type", "render": ptype, "visible": false },
        { "data": "cname" },
        { "data": "quantity", "render": quantityFormat },
        { "data": "tax" },
        { "data": "tax_method", "render": method },
        <?php if ($Admin) { ?>
        { "data": "cost", "render": currencyFormat, "searchable": false },
        <?php } ?>
        { "data": "price", "render": currencyFormat, "searchable": false },
        { "data": "Actions", "searchable": false, "orderable": false }
        ]

    });
});
```

I tried adding the following which gave me an error

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#prTables').DataTable({
        language: {
            url: "//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.24/i18n/French.json"
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

**The error message was:** DataTables warning: table id=prTables - Cannot reinitialise DataTable. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/3

Comment: Do you mean you have two separate `$('#prTables').DataTable({...});` statements on the same page?  You cannot try to create the same DataTable twice like that. Instead, move your `language` option into the first DataTable.

Comment: Also, note that the technique of using a URL without the protocol is old, and is [no longer encouraged](https://www.paulirish.com/2010/the-protocol-relative-url/). You should use this instead: `"https://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.24/i18n/French.json"`

Comment: well am actually struggling to merge the language option into the first DataTable. Can you help me out???

Comment: What happens when you try? I would expect you can just add it after your `"columns"` option:  `"columns": [...], "language": { "url": "https://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.24/i18n/French.json" }`. If that does not work, [edit] your question to show us (a) exactly what you tried, and (b) the text from any errors in the browser console.

Comment: Ok
I will post here after trying